# How can i make my form validator class work?

Tags: php, class, validation

I have made a form validator clas. When you fill in the form on the contact page and click on the submit button it directs you to /contact/submit via $route->add('/contact/submit', function(){ $validator = new Validator($_POST)) });

The form data should compare with the pre filled in $fields array. But for some reason i wont get a response.

I have a function that validates one single value, and a function that loops through the values and use the validate function. I run that function within the constructor.

```
<?php
class Validator 
{
    public $data;

    public $fields = [
        'name'    => [
            'name'  => 'name',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'address'    => [
            'name'  => 'address',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'zipcode'    => [
            'name'  => 'zipcode',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'place'    => [
            'name'  => 'place',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'phone'    => [
            'name'  => 'phone',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'email'    => [
            'name'  => 'email',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'subject'    => [
            'name'  => 'subject',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ],
        'message'    => [
            'name'  => 'message',
            'error' => 'Name is empty.'
        ]
    ];

    public $errors = [];

    public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this->validate($this->data);

    }

    public function validate(){

        foreach($this->fields as $key => $value){
            $this->validate_field($this->fields[$key]);
        }

        if (count($this->errors) == 0) {
            return 'Formulier succesvol ingevuld, wordt verzonden';
        } else {
            return $this->errors;
        }
    }

    public function validate_field($value){
        if (empty($this->data[key($value)])) {
            $this->errors[$value['name']] = $value['error'];
            return;
        }

        $this->data[$value['name']] = htmlspecialchars(trim($value['name']));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code to actually return the response. In your controller you only instantiate validator, and that's all. Did you forget to call it and use the return value to generate a response?

Comment: I used var_dump to see if i got any responses, but there weren't any

Comment: You're returning true/false as a string in validate function. Remove quote and it's response no further used.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how you used `var_dump` and where, and what output did you expect? You never seem to use any return values from any functions.

Comment: I changed the returns and checked if i got errors, but it shows all errors automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually a lot more problems here.

Firstly the variable `$field` in the `validate_field` method doesn't exist. It should be `$value` instead.

Secondly, the `validate` method doesn't accept a method. Therefore it won't do anything. And lastly, if you var_dump your `__constructor`, it should return something. Now it's just a void method.

Also. validate() will always return true, because it returns a string. If you remove the quotes, it will return a boolean.

Your constructor should be:

```
public function __construct($data){
    $this->data = $data;
    return $this->validate();
}
```

Edit:

The illegal offset type warning is caused by passing an array as key.

```
if (empty($this->data[$value])) {
// Should be
if (empty($this->data[key($value)])) {
```

It is also recommended to do an isset check `if (!isset($var) || empty($var))`

Comment: I see you changed your code. The validate method is now returning a boolean as expected.

Comment: I modified the code as you told me to do, but i get this error for every value 
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution to that problem.

Comment: I changed the if statement and added a $ which you forgot in the code, but it says $key is undefined.

Comment: Oh i saw that key($data) was a function and not a variable missing the '$'. Although i don't get anything to return. And no errors either.